# How do you find the key of a dominant seventh chord

Tags: sheet-music

How do you find the key of a dominant seventh chord?

Comment: Chords exist in many keys. In strictly diatonic terms, the root and the fourth will get major seventh chords, and the fifth chord would get the dominant, but as jazz exists, there are many contexts where every major chord would be assumed to be (at least) a dom7.

Comment: @DaveJacoby - in jazz, the subdominant and tonic are more likely to be major sevenths, leaving the dominant as a dom. seventh. In Blues, all three are likely sevenths.

Comment: Because of the lack of information and details in your question it cannot be answered accurately so I am voting to close it. Consider adding more detail to your question if you want an accurate answer. The short answer based on your question the way it is is: “You cannot.”

Comment: Please edit to explain more. There's some understanding that's missing here; right now Tim's answer is right, but I wonder whether either the word "dominant" or "key" is meaning something different to you. For instance, perhaps you want to know how to look at a seventh chord and know what its "name" is, i.e. what the *root* is.

Comment: This question needs some clarification: it's been answered as best we can, with the scant information proffered, but it's not clear enough for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can answer the simplistic question 'If G is the dominant, what is the tonic?'  Find the major (or minor, come to that)  scale of which G is the 5th note.  That's the tonic.   Or, if you know your intervals, go up a perfect 4th or down a perfect 5th to find the tonic.

But 'Dominant 7th' can mean two things.   We might be saying the chord is the actual Dominant of a key, built on the 5th degree of that key's scale.   Or we might just be referring to the shape of chord which is a major triad with a minor 7th on top.  It MIGHT be acting as a functional dominant chord, but it might not.

Typical example, C7, F7, G7, C7.  A simple Blues sequence which comprises a 'dominant 7th' shape chord rooted in the tonic, one rooted on the subdominant and then (finally!) one rooted on the dominant.  All 'dominant 7th' shape chords, all in the same key (but with some chromatic notes) but only one is an actual 'dominant 7th'.

Then  there are 'secondary dominants', chromatic chords which ARE functional but don't lead to the tonic.  In the key of C (and the tonality never centres anywhere else long enough to count as a modulation) let's look at C, E7, A7, D7, G7, C.    Lots of 'dominant 7th' shape chords, only one the actual 'dominant 7th' of the key.

And there are other ways too that 'dominant 7th' shape chords are used in tonal harmony.

Answer (score 0):

The dominant chord is the V of a key. So chord G7: C D E F G. Or to count backwards, C B A G (rule of 9).

The ^3 of a dominant chord is the ^7 of its key. So, with G7 again, ^3 is B. B is the ^7 of key C. And its ^7 is the ^4 of the prevalent key.

BUT - in Blues, all chords will probably be dominant sevenths, including the tonic, so this method won't stand. And there will always be *secondary dominant* chords. those which will by definition, contain non-diatonic notes, a bit of a clue. They ostensibly will be followed by a diatonic chord, but that's not part of the game, or the rules. For example, in key C, E7 is a sec. dom., supposedly leading to (thus dominant of) Am. Or B7, dominant of Em. The same method as above will apply to all secondary dominant seventh chords.

Comment: I thought about answering this in a similar way but it is just too vague. What about Sub V’s or secondary dominants for example? There’s not enough to this question to give a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - I did address sec. doms, but felt that maybe as OP has a score of 1, there may be a simple way to explain.

Comment: Yes, I see you did, too late to erase. Your answer is good, it’s the question that is flawed. You can say where a dominant chord will likely go but that won’t give you information as to what key you’re in.